# How can I make `==` always evaluate to `TRUE`?

Tags: r, metaprogramming, lazy-evaluation, evaluation

This is perhaps an unusual question. I want to know if it's possible to create an object `y` in R for which `x == y` always evaluates to `TRUE`, or possible `NA` (e.g. if `x` is `NA`), whatever the value of `x`.

If necessary, `y` could also be a function call `y()`.

The only way I can think of approaching such a problem is to use `sys.call()` or `sys.calls()`, but so far I've had no luck with that approach.

NB, I have no idea why you would need this behaviour, I'm just interested to know if it can be done.

Comment: do you need to use the `==` or is `all.equal()` an option here

Comment: Would overriding `==` count?

Comment: I'm particularly interested in the use of `==` as I can see how you could go about it using `sys.call()` with `all.equal()`. But if you post a solution with `all.equal()` I'll definitely +1 it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Overriding isn't really what I'm after sorry

Comment: @RHertel You could override it in such a way that it checks whether the second argument is a known sentinel, otherwise revert back to the default behaviour. Of course this still breaks every code that compares to OP’s `y` but that seems explicitly requested.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That's a cool idea... What I'm really interested in is seeing whether anyone can create an object `y` that's clever enough to know its context, or otherwise be able to trick `==`. I'd definitely upvote an answer showing how to override `==` in that way though.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t know of a non-cheat way — your approach of inspecting the call stack is promising but there’s no obvious (to me) way to find the *calling expression* in the call stack so I couldn’t get this to work.

But if we’re willing to cheat, we can do so easily: every operator can be overridden in R so you can redefine `==` however you want.

Maybe (slightly) more realistically useful, you can override (group) generics for specific classes. So you could define a class with the desired semantics of comparing `TRUE` against any other value:

```
# `==` is part of the `Ops` S3 group generic.
Ops.tautology = function (x, y) TRUE

y = structure(list(), class = 'tautology')
```

```
1 == y
# [1] TRUE
2 == y
# [1] TRUE
NA == y
# [1] TRUE
```

This definition of the group generic is too simplistic in practice: it also redefines `+` and basically all other standard binary operators. We’d probably want to dispatch just on `==` but since this is a hack anyway the added complexity isn’t really worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that this is possible, if you allow for `x` to be `NA`.

Consider the below, where we set both `x` and `y` to `NA`.

```
x <- NA
y <- NA
x == y
> [1] NA
```

Comment: Aha! Very good point. I'll edit my question to allow for that, but I'm going to leave it open because what I'm really interested in is seeing how 'clever' the `y` argument can be.